# Querying java.nio.Buffer read/write (flip) state

Tags: java, nio

It seems that there is no method to query a buffer whether it is in read or write state.

Getting the state would be useful in unit tests at least.

What is the best way to get the state?

Comment: When you say "state" are you asking if the buffer is currently reading/writing, or as TAsk's answer says - what capabilities the buffer has?

Comment: It seems like the whole stuff is confusing. If you have a flip() method you have to flip between 2 states...it's common sense....otherwise it should have had a different name (reposition(), etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "read-state" or "write-state" of the `Buffer`. If the buffer supports it, it can be read and write at the same time.

The `flip()` method simply: *"The limit is set to the current position and then the position is set to zero. If the mark is defined then it is discarded."*

There is no internal flip state to be changed here. If you have a prepared buffer holding a thousand bytes, you can read a byte, then write a byte which will overwrite the 2nd...

Comment: So what exactly is `flip()` for then?

Comment: It appears my confusion was deeper. It seems there is no explicit read/write mode "bit" hidden anywhere. The buffer is always ready for reading and writing depending on if implementation supports those at all. At least a comment on this blog post seems to point this way http://java.dzone.com/news/java-nio-question-about-buffer. OTOH this otherwise nice tutorial seems to think there really are 2 modes: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/buffers.html

Comment: People who downvote my answer seems can't read the javadoc. The `flip()` method just changes the position and limit of the buffer. It DOES NOT change an internal variable like `mode`. You can always call the read and write methods if there is data to be read or space to write to.

Comment: @EJP If The flip is simply for managing the limit and position counters when the client code wants to conceptually change from reading to writing.

Comment: @icza I agree. The downvotes are not right. I upvoted you and chose you answer as the correct one. The javadoc could perhaps be more up front about this though. As the links in my other comment seem to suggest, I'm not the only one who was initially confused about this. Maybe my question and your answer will prove useful to others too...

Comment: Agree, the javadoc could be more clear on this, but this isn't the only place where the javadoc could be improved ;)

Comment: Nobody has suggested there is an internal mode. My point is that if buffers were always writable the flip() operation wouldn't exist. The buffer can only be written by flipping it, as per @PeterLamberg's comment. Otherwise the (overloaded) position and limit don't have the appropriate values. It's a stupid design IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to get the state?

There isn't one. The simplest way to manage `Buffers` is to keep them always ready for reading (= putting), and `flip()` them when you want to write(= get), remembering to `compact()` or `clear()` them afterwards so they go back into the read state.

Comment: Sad and pretty stupid to have such a clear action (flip) but not have a clear state. Why do I need to find a simple answer by making computation with limit and position?

Comment: @Alex Even more stupidly, flip() isn't reversible. Very poor choice of name. The idea is to use the state of your program to know the state of the buffer.m or keep them in read state except transiently as per my answer.